# Joomla find file path

Tags: php, joomla, url-rewriting

So, I'm working on a site for a friend, and he got a page he want's me to update. The url looks like this: http://site.dk/index.php/file

I've tried downloading all files down, and search through them via Windows, with no luck. Is there any way I can find the specific file?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Joomla is a database driven CMS `/file` isn't actually a file on the hard disk, its a menu alias that is being processed by `index.php`.

It will mostly likely be pointing to an article in the database, so:

1. login to the /adminstrator section of the website
2. look in the `Menus` for a menu item that has an alias that matches file
3. Open the 'file' menu item to find out what it's pointing to.

The article name is shown in the basic settings for the menu item type, depending on the version of Joomla, it will look like:

#### Joomla 1.5

[image: Joomla 1.5 Single Article Menu Item Paramters(Basic)]

#### Joomla 1.7->2.5

[image: Joomla 2.5 Single Article Menu Item Required Settings]

#### Joomla 3.x

[image: Joomla 3.x Single Article Menu Item Details Tab]

HTH

Comment: it points to this: index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=6 how would I find it from there :D?

Comment: Have a look at the images I've added to my answer.